# Unable to export runnable jar, launch configuration grayed out

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am not able to figure out how to export a runnable jar in eclipse.

I have a java project (project A) (written by someone else) which when imported in Eclipse, I can click `Build Project` and it will create a `projectName.jar` file under `bin/` directory. That jar file contains binary *.class files.

This jar file is added as external library for another java project (project B) which I want to debug. But because all the class files are binary I'm not able to do line-by-line debugging when classes from projectA are called.

I tried exporting `Runnable Jar` in Eclipse, for that I have to select a `Launch Configuration`. But there is no `main` class in project A. (I recursively grepped for `main` and didn't find any).

What can I do to export jar of project A that contains respective source code also (which will be used in line-by-line debugging)?

Comment: Eclipse \ Export \ JAR Export \ 'Export Java source files and resources' checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building there is an option in Eclipse (a check box) to include source code in the JAR, and it has nothing to do with being an executable JAR (an executable JAR must have a class with a `public static void main (String[] args)` method, because that's the entry point).

Comment: Thanks for answer. You mean to say I should export Jar rather than Runnable Jar. I did that, but there is a screen which asks for Java Manifest file. Or alternatively select Main class. What to do at  that screen? edit. nevermind, I selected an option to `Generate manifest file` and gave some path to manifest file. It seems to have worked.

Comment: Eclipse only ask for a main class if you are trying to create a executable jar (as I explained, you need an entry point to start the execution). The manifest file is where you declare it manually.

Answer (score 0):

To export a project to a Runnable Jar in Eclipse, you must at least run your project once as an application.
Run As -> Run Configuration. Double Click "Java Application"
Select the entry class.

Now, you should be able to select a Launch configuration and select a destination for your runnable jar.